# magento2: Enable and Disable log

Tags: magento2, log

How to `enable` or `disable` `log` in `magento2`, **basically my question is about enable and disable logging system in magento2, how we can do that**, also I want to know how to generate custom `log` in `magento2`?

Thanks

Comment: @KeyurShah, the given URL is just telling how to create custom log and which files are helping in doing that. my question is regarding the enable disable concept of log system in magento2, like it does in magento1 from `system > configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings > Enable`

Comment: why this question is mark as duplicate. above question is different from given question Url.