# All Forms Simply Reloading the Page

Tags: forms, submission

I've tried everything on the register forms for a theme I'm working with in Magento. The theme I'm using is Proto. Here's the problem:

• My site is installed on a sandbox environment. Specifically it is on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance. I am just using the standard EC2 URL that comes with the instance during development.

• If I try to submit any forms when the theme is active, nothing works. The pages just reload. This includes registration, login, add to cart, etc.

• If I activate the Magento Blank theme, these forms all work.

• I've inspected the Network events on the signup form for both themes and they both have the same payload. This does not appear to be the issue that most people have where the 'form key' is not on the form. It is there on the theme that doesn't work.

It makes me think this is something with the theme, not with server or with the setup since I can simply just switch themes and it works. It's possible it has something to do with the server side code handling this. I'm suspicious of the theme as well because one of our devs was working on it and I'm not entirely sure he didn't change something crucial.

Other things I've tried:

• I've tailed the apache log for both access and error during the form submissions and see nothing out of the ordinary.

• I've attempted to turn on debug logging through Magento but running this on the command line:

`php bin/magento config:set dev/debug/debug_logging 1 && php bin/magento cache:flush`

per this post: [Magento 2 - Turn on / off debug log](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133156/magento-2-turn-on-off-debug-log) but that debug.log file doesn't appear to show up at all (or I'm not doing anything that is causing it to show up).

---

At this point, I'm just trying to think of new approaches. I'm not very well versed in Magento and just need some other ideas on how I can potentially log/debug/troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: can you add url of your website?

Comment: @Piyush I'd rather not as it's a development work for a client. Is there any sort of additional approach in Magento that may be useful in these types of situations?

Comment: if it is reloading the page you should check from action url

Comment: @Piyush yes it's reloading the same page from the action URL. Most of those forms all have an action URL that is posting to the same page that the form is loading on.

Comment: then you need to changes the forms action url to the proper submit action

Comment: @Piyush I was mistaken. The form does submit to the right URL (in fact it's the same URL for both the blank theme and for the custom theme we are working with). So that is not the issue.