# Hug size of debug.log file in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2

Yesterday I passed my Magento 2.2 to production and the debug.log is collapsing the server every 12 hours. Can someone tell me how to disable the debug.log?

Comment: please refer below link may be it will help you:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133156/magento-2-turn-on-off-debug-log

Comment: Try with php bin/magento config:set dev/debug/debug_logging 0 && php bin/magento cache:flush but The value you set has already been locked.

Comment: Here is the solution https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/logging.html thank so much