# magento 2.3 paypal not working

Tags: magento2, paypal-express

I'm working on a test site with magento 2.3.3 and all the info on pay-pal is correct but the payment not been confirm with pay-pal and no payment been made. the problem is only with live pay-pal not with sandbox. 
have ask pay-pal to check but they say its not pay-pal problem but magento.

what can be the problem?

```
[2020-02-12 09:23:55] main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp',
  'SetExpressCheckout' => 
  array (
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'AMT' => '0.10',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'RETURNURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'CANCELURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'INVNUM' => '000000018',
    'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
    'GIROPAYCANCELURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'GIROPAYSUCCESSURL' => '',
    'BANKTXNPENDINGURL' => '',
    'PAGESTYLE' => 'outletpad',
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'ITEMAMT' => '0.10',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => 'Test Paypal',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '0.10',
    'BUSINESS' => NULL,
    'NOTETEXT' => NULL,
    'EMAIL' => 'dev@magentoguys.com',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'Magento',
    'LASTNAME' => 'developer',
    'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
    'SALUTATION' => NULL,
    'SUFFIX' => NULL,
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'IN',
    'STATE' => 'GJ',
    'CITY' => 'ahmedabad',
    'STREET' => '802 sakar 9',
    'ZIP' => '382415',
    'PHONENUM' => '23412341',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'IN',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'GJ',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'ahmedabad',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => '802 sakar 9',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '382415',
    'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => '23412341',
    'SHIPTOSTREET2' => '',
    'STREET2' => '',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'Magento developer',
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-32666282LX6040010',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2020-02-12T09:23:55Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '2294a07ca2d0d',
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '54140522',
  ),
) [] []
[2020-02-12 14:29:31] main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp',
  'SetExpressCheckout' => 
  array (
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'AMT' => '2.63',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'RETURNURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'CANCELURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'INVNUM' => '000000019',
    'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
    'GIROPAYCANCELURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'GIROPAYSUCCESSURL' => '',
    'BANKTXNPENDINGURL' => '',
    'PAGESTYLE' => 'outletpad',
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'ITEMAMT' => '2.63',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => '3.5mm Stereo In-ear Pink Smile Earphones Cute Face Design Headset',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '2.63',
    'BUSINESS' => NULL,
    'NOTETEXT' => NULL,
    'EMAIL' => NULL,
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'test',
    'LASTNAME' => 'test',
    'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
    'SALUTATION' => NULL,
    'SUFFIX' => NULL,
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'IL',
    'STATE' => 'grgggr',
    'CITY' => 'rfgdfgdg',
    'STREET' => 'dfgdfgdfg',
    'ZIP' => '23435545',
    'PHONENUM' => '234234234',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'IL',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'grgggr',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'rfgdfgdg',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'dfgdfgdfg',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '23435545',
    'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => '234234234',
    'SHIPTOSTREET2' => '',
    'STREET2' => '',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'test test',
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-02F29894057697024',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2020-02-12T14:29:31Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '00f9297d48e6a',
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '54140522',
  ),
) [] []
[2020-02-12 14:32:15] main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp',
  'SetExpressCheckout' => 
  array (
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'AMT' => '2.63',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'RETURNURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'CANCELURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'INVNUM' => '000000019',
    'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
    'GIROPAYCANCELURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'GIROPAYSUCCESSURL' => '',
    'BANKTXNPENDINGURL' => '',
    'PAGESTYLE' => 'outletpad',
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'ITEMAMT' => '2.63',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => '3.5mm Stereo In-ear Pink Smile Earphones Cute Face Design Headset',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '2.63',
    'BUSINESS' => NULL,
    'NOTETEXT' => NULL,
    'EMAIL' => 'e-amz3@live.com',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'test',
    'LASTNAME' => 'test',
    'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
    'SALUTATION' => NULL,
    'SUFFIX' => NULL,
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'IL',
    'STATE' => 'dfsfsf',
    'CITY' => 'sdfsdfsdfs',
    'STREET' => 'sdfsdfsdf',
    'ZIP' => '342342342',
    'PHONENUM' => '234234234234',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'IL',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'dfsfsf',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'sdfsdfsdfs',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'sdfsdfsdf',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '342342342',
    'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => '234234234234',
    'SHIPTOSTREET2' => '',
    'STREET2' => '',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'test test',
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-1XV12411BX485562L',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2020-02-12T14:32:15Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '7556800192ebf',
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '54140522',
  ),
) [] []
[2020-02-12 15:02:27] main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp',
  'SetExpressCheckout' => 
  array (
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'AMT' => '2.63',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'RETURNURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'CANCELURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'INVNUM' => '000000020',
    'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
    'GIROPAYCANCELURL' => 'https://m2.outletpad.com/www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error/',
    'GIROPAYSUCCESSURL' => '',
    'BANKTXNPENDINGURL' => '',
    'PAGESTYLE' => 'outletpad',
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'ITEMAMT' => '2.63',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => '3.5mm Stereo In-ear Pink Smile Earphones Cute Face Design Headset',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '2.63',
    'BUSINESS' => NULL,
    'NOTETEXT' => NULL,
    'EMAIL' => 'e_schnitz@hotmail.com',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'test',
    'LASTNAME' => 'test',
    'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
    'SALUTATION' => NULL,
    'SUFFIX' => NULL,
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'IL',
    'STATE' => 'fgdsgds',
    'CITY' => 'dfgdsg',
    'STREET' => 'dfdsfg',
    'ZIP' => '345345435',
    'PHONENUM' => '2342342',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'IL',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'fgdsgds',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'dfgdsg',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'dfdsfg',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '345345435',
    'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => '2342342',
    'SHIPTOSTREET2' => '',
    'STREET2' => '',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'test test',
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-5M123890EV8446231',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2020-02-12T15:02:27Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '347fe4f32f7a5',
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '54140522',
  ),
) [] []
```

Comment: Tell me clearly what is happening why i cannot understand what you want to say?

Comment: Please see this video with them,
https://www.loom.com/share/33c78b4c1be7463d96b7965a59edf71e

Comment: Ok can i know if this setting activate your admin, screentshot: https://prnt.sc/r1r4o2

Comment: the sanbox is off . this is not the problom.

Answer (score 0):

It seems GetExpressCheckoutDetails method is not calling with Live mode. Have you checked system,exception log? It have any error. Please check and share.

Comment: how i can add the log to this site?

Comment: it is magento default logs. I hope log is already enable.

Comment: i have it  but i dont now how to show it to you over this forum

Comment: If it have any paypal related error then please add here.

Comment: I saying for Magento default log and you can enable it from admin. For reference how to enable log - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133156/magento-2-turn-on-off-debug-log

Comment: see this: https://www.loom.com/share/33c78b4c1be7463d96b7965a59edf71e

Comment: I have checked the video and i am sure that there is some exception was generated. So pls check the system.log, exception.log