# update.log is 64 GB, can I delete it?

Tags: magento2, log, delete

My update.log in /var/log is 64 GB. Can I delete this file or is there another way to prevent the file becoming this big?

Comment: What's in it: 1 line that repeats itself?

Comment: Even so big I think gave a 500 error page, so I have test it when I put it in a backup directory and make the same file if I get any errors, if after a while still no error I know I can delete the backup big size file, thanks for your response!

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/magento2-enable-and-disable-log

Comment: You should set up logrotate (or similar) to avoid having to manually delete this file: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can delete it. Its just a `log`. There will nothing happen if it is not longer available. Delete it and Magento will create another one once it found something to log.

Comment: Thanks @marcel-h ! That's good to know and make of course sense :D